# core data inverse relationship ios

Tags: ios, database, core-data, relationship

just wanted to know how do I create an inverse relationship with one side being **to-One RelationShip** and other side being **to-Many Relationship**.
 Senario is that I am creating a chat messenger where  I have **"Contact"** Entity and **"Message"** Entity. Now, what I want is that relationship from **Message-->Contact** should be **to-One Relationship** while **Contact-->Message** should be **to-Many Relationship** as one Contact can have multiple message. How do I set this?
I have now added the screenshot for my data modal. Please have look and let me know. My P2PChat is **ChatMessage** Class and Contact is **Contacts** Class.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: @SRS: How can you suggest entirely new content for a question asked by a different user? Do you have duplicate accounts? Please consider merging those, or at least posting the changes to your question via the correct username!

Comment: Sorry for that. yeah I have two accounts

Answer (score 1):

1. In your data model you need to add the relationships *contact* and *messages* to Message and Contact entities respectively.
2. Select the inverse relationship of *messages* to be *contact*. (Or you could set the inverse of the of the *contact* relationship to be *message*, either way will work.)
   [image]
3. Select the *messages* relationship on the Contact entity. Then change the 'Type' to 'To Many'.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. How do I add objects to NSOrderedSet in contact ManagedObject Class. AS when ever I am trying to add it it always adds only on e object in it. Could you let me know why it is so, as it is an array so it should add multiple objects instead of adding only last object. Could you let me know what is the problem. Do you need anything from my side?

Comment: Are you using Swift or Objective-C? Just so I know how to answer appropriately.

Comment: I am using Objective-C

Comment: Have you created your NSManagedObject subclasses using Editor->Create Managed Object subclass. In which case, if you look in Contact.h, there should be four methods - addMessagesObject, removeMessagesObject, addMessages and removeMessages. You can use 'addMessages', which takes an NSSet, to add several objects at once.

Comment: I have edited a question by adding screenshot for the data modal.Please let me know

Comment: Which question is that...?

Comment: I can't let you know whether you created the classes using Editor->Create Managed Object Subclass with those screenshots I'm afraid... What exactly is your problem?